# How many Joules does strength values ten through twenty estimate to?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weight

D&D is not a science based or physics based game. Yet certain inquiring players apparently want to know.

Thus, how many Joules does strength values ten through twenty estimate to? Based on lift over head weight listed in the encumbrance chart.

---

Science related info for the problem:

The Prime material plane has been established as being the same as Earth in every aspect not specifically listed as being different (at least for Greyhawk, Forgotten Realms, and Dragonlance), thus for physics purposes, we can assume that Earth-like physics are actually the default when not overridden by psionics, magic, incarnum, etc..

The amount of weight being lifted is exactly equal to the max value listed in the table for every strength value, at sea level with regards to atmospheric pressure and gravity is assumed to be 1G since there is no indication in the primary D&D worlds that it isn't.

Let's assume a human is doing the lifting, for this purpose, in case it makes a difference, using the average height listed in the Height and Weight table.

Comment: How does one measure strength in terms of energy? Power, maybe. Force, sure. But energy? That doesn't make sense. Why is 'amount of weight which can be lifted and carried' inadequate?

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta: [What could be done to improve the question about Joules of energy required to lift in-game objects?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11259/52137)

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate E (the energy, in joules) needed to lift an object to a determined height the following formula can be used:

**E = W x G x H**

Weight of the object being lifted in kilograms (W) times the acceleration of gravity of the location in meters per second squared (G) times the height to which the object is being lifted in meters (H).

Per the question info, gravity is Earth-like, so **G = 9.8m/s^2**.

Also per the question, the creature performing the lifting is a Human of average height, and per the Jump skill rules, the average vertical reach of a Medium sized creature is 8 feet, so this would be the height to which the object is being lifted if the creature raises it over his head, **H = 8 ft. = 2.44m**.

The only variable then is the weight of the object being lifted, which is derived from the maximum load for a bipedal medium creature with a Strength score of 10 through 20:

- 10 => 1083.92 joules
- 11 => 1246.5 joules
- 12 => 1409.1 joules
- 13 => 1625.88 joules
- 14 => 1896.86 joules
- 15 => 2167.84 joules
- 16 => 2493 joules
- 17 => 2818.19 joules
- 18 => 3251.76 joules
- 19 => 3793.7 joules
- 20 => 4335.68 joules